# How to put those 3 buttons on the center of bottom?

Tags: xaml, uwp

In UWP xaml design as below, I split the whole screen to 3 columns and 3 rows. And For row 2 column 1, I need to put a canvas which contains a RelativePanel inside of it. And there will some buttons inside of the panel. My purpose is to make an animation on the panel.

I hope to put those 3 buttons on the bottom/center of the screen, but failed. My layout picture is attached, but it is not what I want.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="15*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Canvas x:Name="toolbarCanvas" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <RelativePanel x:Name="toolbarPanel">
            <Button x:Name="bt1" Margin="50,0,50,0" Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.LeftOf="bt2"/>
            <Button x:Name="bt2" Margin="50,0,50,0" Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>
            <Button x:Name="bt3" Margin="50,0,50,0" Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.RightOf="bt2" />

        </RelativePanel>
    </Canvas>

</Grid>
```

[image: my 3 buttons layout, but it is what I want]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to put those 3 buttons on the center of bottom?

Canvas is a layout panel that supports absolute positioning of child elements relative to the top left corner of the canvas.

```
<Canvas Width="640" Height="480" >
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="30" 
       Fill="Red" Width="200" Height="200" />
</Canvas>
```

For your requirement. Please use `Grid` panel to replace `Canvas` and set toolbarPanel `VerticalAlignment` `HorizontalAlignment`  property like the follow.

```
<Grid x:Name="toolbarGrid" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <RelativePanel x:Name="toolbarPanel" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="bt1" Margin="50,0,50,0" Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.LeftOf="bt2"/>
        <Button x:Name="bt2" Margin="50,0,50,0" Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>
        <Button x:Name="bt3" Margin="50,0,50,0" Height="100" Width="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" RelativePanel.RightOf="bt2" />

    </RelativePanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]